# "Import cycle not allowed" error in Go program

Tags: go

I am new to Go and I am trying to make a program that shows the current time and some other stuff:

```golang
// A terrible program.
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)
// greeting returns a greeting with some info.
func greeting() string {
        return "Hello flat world, the time is: " + time.Now().String()
}
func main() {
        hotelName := "Trivag"
        hotelName += "o"
        fmt.Println(greeting())
        fmt.Println("Hotel: " + hotelName)
}
```

When I try running it with `go run`, it shows an import cycle error:

```
import cycle not allowed
package main
        imports fmt
        imports errors
        imports runtime
        imports internal/bytealg
        imports internal/cpu
        imports runtime
```

These are my Go environment variables from `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="amd64"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/dullgo/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/dullgo/.local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/dullgo/.local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Edit: The .go file was placed directly in the ~/go directory.

Comment: where do you place the file?

Comment: are you sure you perform `go run` on correct file? because I tried your code in my local, I got no issues

Comment: This is weird since [internal/cpu](https://godoc.org/internal/cpu?imports) imports  do not show importing runtime. Do you use an official Golang installation?

Comment: There's something wrong with your Go installation. Clean it out and install an up to date version of Go.

Comment: I just found out that I accidentally set GOBIN instead of GOARCH; I just changed GOBIN to ~/.local/go/bin but it still doesn't work

Comment: No, that's not relevant to the error (your source should not be in `~/go` either, but that's also not the cause of the error). You're going to be much better off if you start with a current release, and use the defaults until you understand how things work.

Comment: I just fixed it. I'm using PythonAnywhere, which has an old version of Go installed at /usr/bin/go. I moved ~/.local/go/bin to the beginning of PATH instead of the end, and now I have a working program that advertises Trivago :)

Comment: Lesson learned here: Place new paths at the end of PATH instead of at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

That error message seems wrong: the `import cycle not allowed` message is supposed to begin and end with the same package path.

Please file an issue by filling out the template at https://golang.org/issue/new.

Comment: package main, imports fmt, imports errors, **imports runtime**, imports internal/bytealg, imports internal/cpu, **imports runtime**

Comment: You should still file an issue with steps to reproduce. On every `go` release I'm aware of, the `internal/cpu` package does not import `runtime`.

Comment: I was using an old version of the `go` program with the new version of everything else that usually goes in `/usr/local/go`